# Entity Framework - Get Updated DB set from context before SaveChanges() is called to add/remove entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I currently have a piece of code to remove or add dates on a calendar if the date  entered is already in the table in my database:

```
foreach (DateTime date in dates)
{
    var dateExists = myDBContext.CalendarDates.Where(x => x.CalendarTypeId == type && x.DateDue == date).FirstOrDefault();
    if(dateExists != null)
    {
        myDBContext.CalendaDates.Remove(dateExists);
    }
    else
    {
        CalendarDate newDate = new CalendarDate
        {
            CalendarTypeId = type,
            Date = date,
        };
        myDBContext.CalendarDates.Add(newDate);
    }
}
```

I would like to do validation before I call `SaveChanges()` to ensure that only one date can be entered for each month and year. Although when I call my CalendarDates `DBSet` from my context, it doesn't seem to be updated to include and disregard the new and removed dates:

```
var dates = myDBContext.CalendarDates.Select(x=> x.Date).ToList();
var uniqueDatesPerMonth = dates.Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1)).Distinct().ToList(); // This should include dates that have been added or removed as per the above code
if(dates.Count() != uniqueDatesPerMonth.Count())
{
    return false;
} else {
    myDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is it possible to get the `DBSet` of the updated table before `SaveChanges()` is called?

Comment: In this scenario, the correct thing to do is to "reserve" a selection for a person for a minute or so, then let them approve their selection. Have you ever bought tickets for an event where you had to select your seats? Same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up discovering about the change tracker that store entities to add and remove entities. I ended up using it to modify my list based on what would be added or removed to the context. It now works as expected:

```
var changeTracker = myDBContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
var dates = myDBContext.CalendarDates.Where(x => x.CalendarTypeId == type).ToList();

foreach(var entity in changeTracker)
{
    var addRemoveDate = (CalendarDate)entity.Entity;
    if(addRemoveDate.Id > 0)
    {
        timeAllocationDates.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == addRemoveDate.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        timeAllocationDates.Add(addRemoveDate);
    }
}

var uniqueDatesPerMonth = dates.Select(x => new DateTime(x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month, 1)).Distinct().ToList();
if (dates.Count() != uniqueDatesPerMonth.Count())
{
    return false;
} 
else 
{
    myDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```